# IMPORTRANGE QUERY formula filtered by dates range and values from cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Sheet1","QC sheet!A792:B10000"), "Select Col2, Col4 where Col2 contains '"&B$1&"' and Col4 contains '"&C1&"' and date "&TEXT(G1,"'YYY-MM-DD'")&" <=Col1 and date "&TEXT(H1,"'YYY-MM-DD'")&" >=Col1" ,0)))
```

Using above formula to count data with 2 containing conditions along with start and end date does not work.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hMoJAtBeXKGMFcghMDZaIcBjfJAD9mF35YVXbXYZ5Iw/edit#gid=597186154

---

**EDIT 1:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DTMFViXxBn-ezPJ2Njjbor-4udoRyc8M/view?usp=sharing
Please update the formula sheet have been attached.

**Edit 2:**

```
=COUNTIFS(D3:D50,A1,E3:E50,B1,C3:C50,">0",C3:C50,F1,C3:C50,G1)
```

This formula is working but how we can calculate same with query formula actually i have to get data by importrange.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to [share a Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two mistakes in your query formula.

1. `IMPORTRANGE("Sheet1","QC sheet!A792:B10000")` can not return anything. The reason being that you need to replace the `Sheet` part of the formula with the sheet's `ID` that you want to import from. 
   *(More info about [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340))*
2. You mention `Col4` when you import just 2 columns `A` and `B` from `sheet!A792:B10000`.
   *(More info about [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB))*

I do not know about the rest of it (no obvious mistakes) since I cannot access your sheet.
*(Please read how to [share a Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.)*

Correct the formula, see if it works for you and let us know.

---

> EDIT *(following the fixed sheet)*

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("191k0EcOCZKzorxG5jb-H6vIM6GKGzq2r8638q2Yc7fA","C3:F100")}, 
                           "Select Col2 where Col2 contains '"&A$1&"' 
                                          and Col3 contains '"&B1&"' 
                                          and Col1>= date"&TEXT(F1,"'YYY-MM-DD'")&" 
                                          and Col1<= date"&TEXT(G1,"'YYY-MM-DD'")&"",0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Dear Your formula is correct but when the dates change then it gives 0 value.

If i select 01/01/2020 on both sides then answer is 0

Comment: Formula corrected

Comment: Have you tried the new formula? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.